# How to see all the messages a mock received with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking

I'm using rspec to write some tests, since I met some very strange problems, I want to see all the messages a mock received.

Say I have defined a `null_object`:

```
user = mock("user").as_null_object

// do a lot of things on user
user.xxx1();
user.xxx2();
...
```

Now I want to see all the messages that `user` received, is it possible?

Comment: `RSpec::Mocks.space.proxy_for(user).instance_eval { @messages_received }` would work, but I hope there's a better way …